# Python - Accessing fields in a JSON

Tags: python, json

Im having trouble accessing some certain fields that I get from a JSON API, in the API if a user is part of more than one on_call policy I don't know how to access the second or more policies. My current code just returns Bob Brown twice under the network team policy, instead of bob brown twice under network team and solarwinds test

JSON sample

```
{
    "users": [{
        "id": "PN8PIFR",
        "name": "Bob Brown",
        "user_url": "/users/PN8PIFR",
        "invitation_sent": false,
        "marketing_opt_out": false,
        "on_call": [{
            "level": 2,
            "start": "2016-05-30T08:00:00Z",
            "end": "2016-06-06T08:00:00Z",
            "escalation_policy": {
                "id": "PYZTEI3",
                "name": "Network Team"
            }
        }, {
            "level": 1,
            "start": null,
            "end": null,
            "escalation_policy": {
                "id": "P3CBIDO",
                "name": "Solarwinds Test"
            }
        }],
        "job_title": "Network Engineer"
    }, {
        "id": "PLIMHAI",
        "name": "Bill Blue",
        "user_url": "/users/PLIMHAI",
        "invitation_sent": false,
        "marketing_opt_out": false,
        "on_call": [{
            "level": 1,
            "start": "2016-06-02T08:00:00Z",
            "end": "2016-06-03T06:00:00Z",
            "escalation_policy": {
                "id": "PARVPQB",
                "name": "DBA Team"
            }
        }],
        "job_title": "Database Administrator"
    }],
    "active_account_users": 9,
    "limit": 25,
    "offset": 0,
    "total": 6
}
```

view.py

```
class User(object):
    __attrs = ['PolicyID','Level','LevelNo', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'StartTime',
               'EndTime', 'Name', 'Mobile']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attr in self.__attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, kwargs.get(attr, None))

    def __repr__(self):
        return ', '.join(
            ['%s: %r' % (attr, getattr(self, attr)) for attr in self.__attrs])          




### Get the Policy data ###
objPolicyData = getuser_data()
pdUsers = pdUser.objects.all()

### Index View ###
@login_required
def index(request):
    OnCallData = [] 
    for user_item_data in objPolicyData['users']:   
        user_data = User()     
        #get the user object from DB
        model_pd_user       = pdUser.objects.get(PagerDutyID=user_item_data['id'])
        user_data.Name   = model_pd_user.Name
        user_data.Mobile = model_pd_user.Mobile
        for on_call_data in user_item_data['on_call']:    
            user_data.LevelNo         = on_call_data['level']
            user_data.Level           = getLevel(on_call_data['level'])
            user_data.StartDate       = getDate(on_call_data['start'])
            user_data.EndDate         = getDate(on_call_data['end'])
            user_data.StartTime       = getTime(on_call_data['start'])
            user_data.EndTime         = getTime(on_call_data['end'])    
            user_data.PolicyID    = on_call_data['escalation_policy']['id']
            OnCallData.append(user_data)
```

Comment: Please include your exception/error

Comment: Print the values in your iterations, I think you are overwriting in the same object

Comment: @JanvanderVegt Is probably right because you create `user_data` before you start looping over `user_item_data['on_call']`. You should create a new one on each iteration to prevent this.

Comment: i think that has done it!